# Blender & 3Dconnexion

Tags: 3dconnexion

my input data:
Blender 3.3.1
3dconnexion
SpaceMouse Enterprise

The top panel with numpad in 3dconnexion does not work. The NDOF panel works very well, but I can’t assign a single button to the top panel.
Has anyone encountered such a problem?

I want to say right away that I tried everything that came to my mind and I have “emulate numpad” enabled.
I really hope for you

Comment: We can't help you on external software, we can only solve Blender issues. Thus, I'm voting down for now but don't hesitate to update your question / open a new one, if you have an issue on the Blender side ! We'll gladly help.

Comment: "I want to say right away that I tried everything that came to my mind and I have “emulate numpad” enabled. " - it seems to me we would need to be able to read your mind to know what it is that came to your mind.

Comment: @Lutzi So im not big specialist. But in the other app this simulator work perfect. I have a problem only in blender and only with numpad panel. And I was thinking that's  its about Blender.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I think my mind its not general) if you know about this problem and have solution.